# Created a brand new Django Project, attempting to run the server generates an Improperly Configured Error

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have been working on a Django Project for a bit, until I took a break. One month later I dug back in to the project and went to run the server. I received an error:
 `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

I figured I must have tweaked something by accident. So I created a brand new Django Project (using a virtual environment), and just went to test the server. I received the same error. I tried the `python manage.py shell` solution listed in another answers but to no avail.

If it helps I'm on Linux with Django version 2.1.5 and Python 3.6.

**Edit:**

If anyone encounters something similar I found using `python3 manage.py runserver` works in place of using `django-admin`. Per Greg's answer below, I did begin to receive a new error `ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named "mysite" exists`. I will continue to search for an answer on that front.

Comment: What do you get if you run "env | grep DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" in bash?

Also, have you already activated your virtual environment?

Comment: Nothing is returned. And fortunately yes I'm in my venv.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of the comments here.

If "env | grep DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" returns empty, it means you have to set an environment variable stating where your settings.py file is located.

This can be done by doing the following:
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings

Be sure to replace "mysite" with the name of your app!

Comment: would that be done under the .bashrc? or some other place?

Comment: If you're using virtualenv, then the best place to do this would actually be in the activate script (the same script called when running "source venv/bin/activate")

If you place the export statement in that script, then every time you activate your virtualenv the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE will be set.

Comment: When not using virtualenv though, bashrc would be the right place to do so!

Comment: now it provides a "mysite" module not found... Do i have to create a "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" variable and set it to point to mysite path?